# facebook graph api authentification error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my web site I want to use fb graph api. I write next code

```
require_once 'facebook.php';
$fb = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => ID,
'secret' => SECRET,
'cookie' => true
));

$user = $fb->getUser();

if($user) {
} else {
$params = array(
'scope' => 'publish_stream,,offline_access',
'fbconnect' => 1,
'redirect_uri' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
);
$url = $fb->getLoginUrl($params);

header("Location: $url");
exit();
}
```

But after first open page this code request access to my app and then try again and again get user.
When I try to do

```
try {
$ret_obj = $fb->api('/me');
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
print_r($e)
}
```

I see error 'An active access token must be used to query information about the current user'.

Anybody knows where is error?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug see: [facebook access token working on one page only](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13745707/) it was fixed last night so update your facebook api and you should be good.  Also you've got two ,,'s in your scope. It will probably still work but still I'd remove one.

Comment: There are not all clear for me. When I try to do `try {
    $facebook_uid = $facebook->getUser(); 

    $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $fbuser = $facebook->api('/me');

 }catch(Exception $e) {

     $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_396582000367255_access_token'];
     $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
 }` I see error 'Undefined index'

Comment: No, that was a work around pointing to the FB bug.  The bugs been fixed last night.  So update the facebook SDK and you won't get the error you were getting.  I provided the SO link so you could understand the problem and see the FB bug.